# Nightmare / Electron : Navigation Error (code - 118)

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

Scraping with nightmare has been a breeze until recently , i started encountering errors with no details and the title "navigation error"
and the error code 118 as shown below.

```
{ [Error: navigation error]
```

'0': 
   { message: 'navigation error',
     code: -118,
     details: '',
     url: 'http://markets.ft.com/research/Browse-Companies' },
  length: 1,
  errors: 
   [ { message: 'navigation error',
       code: -118,
       details: '',
       url: 'http://markets.ft.com/research/Browse-Companies' } ] }

My nightmare code (Node.Js) :

```
 function *run(){

var nightmare = Nightmare({show : true });
nightmare.useragent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
var url = "http://markets.ft.com/research/Browse-Companies";
var industry = [];

//fetching data in { INDUSTRY , LINK , SECTOR } format .

yield nightmare.goto(url).inject('js' , './jquery-2.2.3.min.js').wait('#wsod').evaluate(function () {

    var arr = [];

    $('.simpleLinkList.wsodModuleContent li').each(function(){
        arr.push({SECTOR : $(this).parents('ul').prev().text().replace('Sectors & Industries' , '') ,
            INDUSTRY : $(this).text() , LINK : $(this).find('a').attr('href')});
    })

    return arr;

}).then(function (data) {
    industry = data;
});

//using {LINK}

var companies = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i<2; i++)
{

    yield nightmare.goto(industry[i].LINK).inject('js' , './jquery-2.2.3.min.js').wait('#wsod');
    var nextExists = yield nightmare.visible('.wsod-icon-paging-next-active');
    var maxpage = 3;
    var currentpage = 1;
    var data = []; /* Object({ Name: "" , Link : ""})*/

    while(nextExists && currentpage < maxpage)
    {
        //pagination / checking if next page exists and looping the scraper for each page

        yield nightmare.evaluate(function(a , b){
            var obj = [];
            $('.company-link').each(function () {
                obj.push({Sector : a , Industry: b , Name: $(this).text() , Link: $(this).attr('href')});
            });

            return obj;
        },industry[i].SECTOR  , industry[i].INDUSTRY).then(function (obj) {
            data.push(obj);
        });


        yield nightmare.click('.wsod-icon-paging-next-active').wait(2000);

        currentpage++;
        nextExists = yield nightmare.visible('.wsod-icon-paging-next-active');
    }

    //data is an array of arrays and needs to be flattened.

    var x  = [].concat.apply([] , data);

    //now pushing data to companies list (entire container)

    companies.push(x);
}

companies = [].concat().apply([], companies);

//now companies is an array of entire list of all companies in every single      sector->industry with sector name included for ease

console.log(companies);*/
console.log(companies);

yield nightmare.end();

}
```

If anyone could provide more info regarding this error , it would be great . The program works some times but most times i get the "Navigation-error"

Answer (score 2):

Alright , after some research through the chromium docs which powers electron+nightmare .

Error code -118 relates to a time-out , however this issue pops up on websites that load instantly on a real chromium browser .

Seems like an electron bug for now , if anyone knows more please do provide the details.