# Cron and nightmare js

Tags: javascript, cron, nightmare

I am trying to run a cron with nightmare js locally.
Unfortunately I have this error.

```
Unhandled rejection (<{"message":"navigation error","code":-...>, no stack trace)
```

Related issue : [Nightmare JS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719236/nightmare-js-not-working)

I was wondering if it is linked with the fact that nightmare require a graphical interface?

Thanks for your help,

EDIT

In my cron, I have one Promise function which is composed of the cron followed by promises.

```
var job = new CronJob('* */10 * * * *', function() {
    crawl()
  }, function () {
    console.log("crawl ended")
  },
  true
);


job.start();
```

Here is what nightmare looks like:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  typeInterval: 300,
  show: true
});

nightmare
  .goto('https://pageThatRequireToLoginThenDiplayJsonAsText.com')
  .type('[name=email]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=email]', 'myemail')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', 'mypassword')
  .click('[type=submit]')
  .wait(25000)
  .wait(25000)
  .evaluate(function (page, done) {

    document.documentElement
    done()
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    // fs.writeFileSync('testOutput.json', JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('failed:', error);
  });
```

When I run the function crawl without cron it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was in the settings of the cron. 
I'd rather use

```
var job = new CronJob('* 10 * * * *', function() {
    crawl()
  }, function () {
    console.log("crawl ended")
  },
  true
);
```

Plus I had to redefine nightmare settings INTO my function.

```
var get_data = function(){
  var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
  var nightmare = Nightmare({
    typeInterval: 300,
    show: true
  });
  nightmare
  .goto('https://pageThatRequireToLoginThenDiplayJsonAsText.com')
  .type('[name=email]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=email]', 'myemail')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', 'mypassword')
  .click('[type=submit]')
  .wait(25000)
  .wait(25000)
  .evaluate(function (page, done) {

    document.documentElement
    done()
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    // fs.writeFileSync('testOutput.json', JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('failed:', error);
  });
}
```

Instead of

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  typeInterval: 300,
  show: true
});

var get_data = function(){
  nightmare
  .goto('https://pageThatRequireToLoginThenDiplayJsonAsText.com')
  .type('[name=email]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=email]', 'myemail')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', '')
  .wait(1000)
  .type('[name=password]', 'mypassword')
  .click('[type=submit]')
  .wait(25000)
  .wait(25000)
  .evaluate(function (page, done) {

    document.documentElement
    done()
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    // fs.writeFileSync('testOutput.json', JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('failed:', error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay right off the bat I am unsure whether I am correct or not because I do not have too much experience with this and you have not specified what you defined in your cron. But from the quick search I made what you are surmising is kind of correct. When you are using cron your calls made through commandline. Now Nightmare is built on Electron which in turn depends on Chromium. Now from what I  learnt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144314/nightmare-electron-navigation-error-code-118), Electron might have a bug that causes a timeout every time a page loads instantly on a real chromium browser. So from what I gather thus far, your app needs Electron communicating with Chromium to be working properly which in your case it doesn't seem to be doing. I am sorry for being vague and possibly wrong but its the best I could come up with so little info.

Comment: Good on you for trying to help with such a vague problem. +1

Comment: Thanks for your help Ayaskant.
I'll try to work with PhantomJS.

Comment: @QuentinDel nightmare is vastly superior

Comment: @naomik 
Thanks for your tips
I asked a more precise question with nightmare here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379389/cron-and-nightmarejs